# androidのgetSupportActionBarのエラー

Tags: java, android

下記のコードのgetSupportActionBarのところにエラー(cannot resolve method)が出てしまいます。
何故でしょうか。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    private EditText urlText;
    private static final String INITIAL_URL = "http://doctormouse.me/";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlText);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(view.getTitle());
                urlText.setText(url);
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl(INITIAL_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getSupportActionBar()`はsupport libraryを使用している時に使うメソッドなので、

- サポートライブラリを使わず、`getActionBar()`に変える（ただしminSDKVersion >= 11)
- `extends Activity`ではなく、`extends AppCompatActivity`にする(ライブラリにsupport-v7の追加が必要）

のどちらかで対応してください（多くの場合は後者の`AppCompatActivity`を使うことになると思いますが）